# custom form validation going wrong in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, validation

My custom function is not working. I am checking if passed value does not exist in the database it return error message. What I am doing wrong?
**Controller function**

```
function sp_exists($str)
        {
            $this->user_model->sp_exists($str);
            $this->form_validation->set_message('sp_exists', 'The %s field does not exists');
        }
```

**Model function**

```
function sp_exists($str)
    {
        $this->db->where('member_id',$str);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**callback function**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('sponsor_id', 'Sponsor ID', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_sp_exists');
```

Comment: What's it outputting currently?

Comment: just the field is being blank but not submitting the form.

Comment: Your callback function isn't returning anything at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you look at the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks)? It explains clearly how to do this.

First of all I think you should change the model function to this:

```
function sp_exists($str)
{
  $this->db->where('member_id',$str);
  $query = $this->db->get('user');
  return $query->num_rows() > 0;
}
```

And the controller should look like this:

```
function sp_exists($str)
{
  if(!$this->user_model->sp_exists($str))
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('sp_exists', 'The %s field does not exists');
    return FALSE;
  }
  else
  {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: I did the change, but still it is not working. And I am not making mistake to load the library. I can't figure out what is going wrong with it.

Comment: Could you show your form code too? What exactly is not working? Please try to describe exactly what happens when you submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
function sp_exists($str)
    {
        $this->user_model->sp_exists($str);
        $this->form_validation->set_message('sp_exists', 'The %s field does not exists');
    }
```

to

```
function sp_exists($str)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('sp_exists', 'The %s field does not exists');
        return $this->user_model->sp_exists($str);
    }
```